# Textcomplete for the whole sentence with .textcomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use textcomplete for the entire sentence. I have tried alot of different regular expressions, but the ".textcomplete" still just search for the first word in the sentence.

Someone good at this?

```
$('#search').textcomplete([{
    words: array,
    match: /\b(\w{1,})$/,
    search: function (term, callback) {
        term = term.toLowerCase();
        callback($.map(array, function (word) {
            return word.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
        }));
    },
    select: function (value, strategy) {
        this.adapter.select(value, strategy);
        this.fire('change').fire('textComplete:select', value, strategy);
        this.adapter.focus();
    },
    index: 1,
    replace: function (word) {
        return word;
    },

}], {
    onKeydown: function (e, commands) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 74) { // CTRL-Enter
            return commands.KEY_ENTER;
        }
    }

});
```

[Working with the first word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN2ZH.png)

[Autocomplete stops when pressing space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjZNS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because your regex does not match white space!

```
match: /\b(\w{1,})$/
```

w is a shorthand matching any words but not space.
Use a regex to match any word and space instead:

```
match: /\b([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{1,})$/
```

Try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/p5qqvkp6/12/